# How to enable Mobile Broadband in Dell Latitude 5591?

Tags: dell, mobile-broadband

I have a Dell Latitude 5591 with Ubuntu 18.04 installed (GUI is XFCE4). It comes with a mobile broadband embedded device. I inserted a SIM card in the tray and want to use it but I cannot find the broadband option in my network manager.

I manually added a broadband connection and inserted the default values for my provider but still I cannot see the connection in my network manager. I believe I'm missing the broadband driver or something needs to be enabled for it work. Any idea how can I go about this?

Here's the output of `lspci`:

```bsh
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a368 (rev 10)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a369 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a353 (rev 10)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a338 (rev f0)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a33d (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a30e (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM (rev 10)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce MX130] (rev a2)
3b:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

I don't know if the mobile broadband is one of these or is it missing in the first place and requires purchasing a separate H/W. What puzzles me is that the laptop comes with a SIM card tray, indicating there's a broadband modem inside.

Comment: Please try finding out the specific hardware and [edit] the question to add that information. Try running `lspci` in terminal and look for a line describing it.

Comment: Added the the output of the `lspci`. Cannot find broadband on the list.

Comment: Also try `lsusb` but if you can't find it in that bus either, I'm out of ideas. It's either connected differently than usual or doesn't exist at all. It's an optional component, having the tray for the SIM doesn't mean it has a WWAN card installed.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I think you're correct that it might not be there in the first place. I will inspect the hardware and fit in one if it's not there.